# A string that represents encoded characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, decode

I use python 2.7 and I have the following string: `mystr = '\xde\x05\xd7\x05\xe9\x05\xd1\x05'`
I want to get the real unicode string out of it: `myuni = u'\u05de\u05d7\u05e9\u05d1'`.
The encoding is "cp1255".

How can I get this done?

Thank you!

Comment: Show us something you did so far..

Comment: That is not CP1255 encoded data. Given your expected output, you'd expect `'\xee\xe7\xf9\xe1'` instead. You have UTF-16 instead.

Comment: @qqvc But it didn't work at all. For example: mystr.decode("cp1255") -->
*** UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0xde in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh wow so that was it! mystr.decode("utf16") returned what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have CP1255 data. You have UTF-16 (little endian) data instead:

```
>>> mystr = '\xde\x05\xd7\x05\xe9\x05\xd1\x05' 
>>> mystr.decode('utf-16-le')
u'\u05de\u05d7\u05e9\u05d1'
```

CP1255 looks like this:

```
>>> u'\u05de\u05d7\u05e9\u05d1'.encode('cp1255')
'\xee\xe7\xf9\xe1'
```

Comment: Thanks! When I do mystr.decode('utf-16') it works too, how is that?

Comment: @EllaShar: then your system is little-endian by default. It'd fail on a big-endian system. A full string would include a BOM (byte order mark) at the start to indicate what byte order to use.